# Spring boot - taking control of 404 Not Found

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to figure out the simplest way to take control over the 404 Not Found handler of a basic Spring Boot RESTful service such as the example provided by Spring:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Rather than have it return the default Json output:

```
{
  "timestamp":1432047177086,
  "status":404,
  "error":"Not Found",
  "exception":"org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException",
  "message":"No handler found for GET /aaa, ..."
}
```

I'd like to provide my own Json output.

By taking control of the `DispatcherServlet` and using `DispatcherServlet#setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true)`, I was able to make it throw an exception in case of a 404 but I can't handle that exception through a `@ExceptionHandler`, like I would for a `MissingServletRequestParameterException`. Any idea why?

Or is there a better approach than having a NoHandlerFoundException thrown and handled?

Comment: May be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21061638/spring-mvc-how-to-return-custom-404-errorpages) will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Spring documentation appendix A.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) there is a boolean property called `spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found` which can be used to enable throwing `NoHandlerFoundException`. Then you can create exception handler like any other.

```
@RestControllerAdvice
class MyExceptionHandler {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyExceptionHandler.class);

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    public String handleNoHandlerFoundException(NoHandlerFoundException ex) {
        log.error("404 situation detected.",ex);
        return "Specified path not found on this server";
    }
}
```

`@ExceptionHandler` itself without `@ControllerAdvice` (or `@RestControllerAdvice`) can't be used, because it's bound to its controller only.

Answer (score 5):

It works perfectly Fine.

When you are using SpringBoot, it does not handle (**404 Not Found**) explicitly; it uses **WebMvc** error response. If your Spring Boot should handle that exception, then you should do some hack around Spring Boot. For 404, the exception class is **NoHandlerFoundException**; if you want to handle that exception in your **@RestControllerAdvice** class, you must add **@EnableWebMvc** annotation in your Application class and set **setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);** in DispatcherServlet. Please refer to the following code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebMvc
public class Application {  
    @Autowired
    private DispatcherServlet servlet;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner getCommandLineRunner(ApplicationContext context) {
        servlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
        return args -> {};
    }
}
```

After this you can handle **NoHandlerException** in your **@RestControllerAdvice** class

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class AppException {

    @ExceptionHandler(value={NoHandlerFoundException.class})
    @ResponseStatus(code=HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public ApiError badRequest(Exception e, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new ApiError(400, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.getReasonPhrase());
    }
}
```

I have created ApiError class to return customized error response

```
public class ApiError {
    private int code;
    private String message;
    public ApiError(int code, String message) {
        this.code = code;
        this.message = message;
    }
    public ApiError() {
    }   
    //getter & setter methods...
}
```

Comment: adding @EnableWebMvc should totally switch off Spring Boot's auto-configuration for Spring MVC - so all spring.mvc.* configuration properties will be ignored. See the reference documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-auto-configuration.

Answer (score 2):

In short, the `NoHandlerFoundException` is thrown from the Container, not from your application within your container. Therefore your Container has no way of knowing about your `@ExceptionHandler` as that is a Spring feature, not anything from the container.

What you want is a `HandlerExceptionResolver`. I had the very same issue as you, have a look at my solution over there: [How to intercept "global" 404s on embedded Tomcats in spring-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31778296/how-to-intercept-global-404s-on-embedded-tomcats-in-spring-boot/31790568#31790568)

Answer (score 1):

The `@EnableWebMvc` based solution can work, but it might break Spring boot auto configurations.
The solution I am using is to implement `ErrorController`:

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyErrorController implements ErrorController {

        private static final String ERROR_PATH = "/error";

        @NonNull
        private final ErrorAttributes errorAttributes;

        @RequestMapping(value = ERROR_PATH)
        Map<String, Object> handleError(WebRequest request) {
            return errorAttributes.getErrorAttributes(request, false);
        }

        @Override
        public String getErrorPath() {
            return ERROR_PATH;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this problem is:

- Configure DispatcherServlet to throw and exception if it doesn't find any handlers.
- Provide your implementation for the exception that will be thrown from DispatcherServlet, for this case is the `NoHandlerFoundException`.

Thus, in order to configure DispatcherServlet you may use properties file or Java code.
Example for properties.yaml,

```
spring:
    mvc:
      throw-exception-if-no-handler-found: true
```

Example for properties.properties,

```
spring.mvn.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
```

Example for Java code, we just want to run the command `servlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);` on startup, I use the `InitializingBean` interface, you may use another way. I found a very well written guide to run logic on startup in spring from [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/running-setup-logic-on-startup-in-spring).

```
@Component
public class WebConfig implements InitializingBean {

    @Autowired
    private DispatcherServlet servlet;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        servlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
    }

}
```

**Be careful!** Adding @EnableWebMvc disables autoconfiguration in Spring Boot 2, meaning that if you use the annotation @EnableWebMvc then you should use the Java code example, because the `spring.mvc.*` properties will not have any effect.

After configuring the DispatcherServlet, you should override the `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` which is called when an Exception is thrown. We want to override the action when the `NoHandlerFoundException` is thrown, like the following example.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyApiExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleNoHandlerFoundException(NoHandlerFoundException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        String responseBody = "{\"errormessage\":\"WHATEVER YOU LIKE\"}";
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, responseBody, headers, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, request);
    }
}
```

Finally, adding a break point to method `handleException` of `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` might be helpful for debugging.

Comment: spring.resources.add-mappings=false  I have to add this for 404 in spring boot