# Spring Boot Rest - How to configure 404 - resource not found

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I got a working spring boot rest service. When the path is wrong it doesn't return anything. No response At all. At the same time it doesn't throw error either. Ideally I expected a 404 not found error.

I got a GlobalErrorHandler

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalErrorHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

}
```

There is this method in ResponseEntityExceptionHandler

```
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleNoHandlerFoundException(NoHandlerFoundException ex, HttpHeaders headers,
                                                     HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {

    return handleExceptionInternal(ex, null, headers, status, request);
}
```

I have marked `error.whitelabel.enabled=false` in my properties

What else must I do for this service to throw a 404 not found response back to clients

I referred a lot of threads and don't see this trouble faced by anybody.

This is my main application class

```
 @EnableAutoConfiguration // Sprint Boot Auto Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.xxxx")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.xxxxxxxx") // To segregate MongoDB
                                                        // and JPA repositories.
                                                        // Otherwise not needed.
@EnableSwagger // auto generation of API docs
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableConfigurationProperties

public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static Class<Application> appClass = Application.class;

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(appClass).properties(getProperties());

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean correlationHeaderFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean filterRegBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        filterRegBean.setFilter(new CorrelationHeaderFilter());
        filterRegBean.setUrlPatterns(Arrays.asList("/*"));

        return filterRegBean;
    }

    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    static Properties getProperties() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("spring.config.location", "classpath:/");
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurerAdapter webMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        WebMvcConfigurerAdapter webMvcConfigurerAdapter = new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
                configurer.favorPathExtension(false).favorParameter(true).parameterName("media-type")
                        .ignoreAcceptHeader(false).useJaf(false).defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .mediaType("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            }
        };
        return webMvcConfigurerAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping defaultAnnotationHandlerMapping() {
        RequestMappingHandlerMapping bean = new RequestMappingHandlerMapping();
        bean.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 35):

The solution is pretty easy:

**First** you need to implement the controller that will handle all error cases. This controller must have `@ControllerAdvice` -- required to define `@ExceptionHandler` that apply to all `@RequestMappings`.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlerController {

    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value= HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @ResponseBody
    public ErrorResponse requestHandlingNoHandlerFound() {
        return new ErrorResponse("custom_404", "message for 404 error code");
    }
}
```

Provide exception you want to override response in `@ExceptionHandler`. `NoHandlerFoundException` is an exception that will be generated when Spring will not be able to delegate request (404 case). You also can specify `Throwable` to override any exceptions.

**Second** you need to tell Spring to throw exception in case of 404 (could not resolve handler):

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebMvc
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = (DispatcherServlet)ctx.getBean("dispatcherServlet");
        dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
    }
}
```

Result when I use non defined URL

```
{
    "errorCode": "custom_404",
    "errorMessage": "message for 404 error code"
}
```

**UPDATE**: In case you configure your SpringBoot application using `application.properties` then you need to add the following properties instead of configuring `DispatcherServlet` in main method (thanks to @mengchengfeng):

```
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
spring.web.resources.add-mappings=false
```

Comment: Thank you. Even after doing this change i am still not seeing no response. Please help!!!

Comment: Can you post your filter implementation? CorrelationHeaderFilter will handle every request and might be the reason why it doesn't work for you. I tested with a code very close to yours and it working if I comment filter, add '@EnableWebMvc', and comment not needed annotation for it like '@EnableSwagger', '@@EnableJpaRepositories', '@@EnableAspectJAutoProxy'.

Comment: I can post simple application to github if you want

Comment: In case anybody else runs into problems with the code example, the custom ControllerAdvice worked for my **Spring Boot** application when I configured the dispatcher servlet using properties as opposed to inside of main:

`spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
spring.resources.add-mappings=false`

After I removed the dispatcherServlet configuration in main and used the above two properties in application.properties, errors were properly routed to my ControllerAdvice. Hope this helps somebody!

Comment: Please post the ErrorResponse class to make this answer complete.

Comment: When I add ErrorResponse class as a model, I cant get my custom 404  error message. error log: `No converter found for return value of type: class co.x.model.ErrorResponse `

can you help me ?

Comment: @AhmetCanAkgül Make sure that you have `jackson-databind` is in your dependencies and that your ErrorResponse and nested classes has getters and setters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32905917/how-to-return-json-data-from-spring-controller-using-responsebody or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33832735/spring-boot-application-no-converter-found-for-return-value-of-type

Comment: this is further improved in spring boot latest versions

Comment: This really helped but replaced `spring.resources.add-mappings=false`  which is deprecated by `spring.web.resources.add-mappings=false` in Spring boot 2+. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but here is another way to configure the `DispatcherServlet` in code but not in the main class. You can use a separate `@Configuration` class:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class ExceptionHandlingConfig {

    @Autowired
    private DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet;

    @PostConstruct
    private void configureDispatcherServlet() {
        dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
    }
}
```

Please not that this does not work without the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add this to your Properties file.

   ```
    spring:
       mvc:
         throw-exception-if-no-handler-found: true
       web:
         resources:
           add-mappings: false
   ```
2. In your `@ControllerAdvice` class add this:

   ```
   @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
      public ResponseEntity<Object> handleNoHandlerFound404() {
      return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);;
   }
   ```