# Custom exception handler for NoHandlerFoundException is not working without @EnableWebMvc

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to override html error page for 404 responses as an JSON response. When i use `@ControllerAdvice` without `@EnableWebMvc` it is not working.

```
@EnableWebMvc   // if i remove this, it is not working
@ControllerAdvice
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {
    
    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorDTO> noHandlerFoundException(
                    HttpServletRequest request, 
                    NoHandlerFoundException exception) {

        ErrorDTO errorDTO = new ErrorDTO();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDTO, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

Is there an option for custom exception handling without `@EnableWebMvc`, because it overrides Spring configurations which are declared inside application.yml.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I easily resolved problem by adding one of configurations in application.yml.

```
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
spring.resources.add-mappings=false
```

or

```
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern: /static
```

If you don't restrict Spring and no handler matches with your request, then spring tries to look for static content.

Answer (score 12):

Normally @utkusonmez answer works fine but not in my case, as I am using swagger. So all I did is add following properties in my `application.properties` file

```
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/swagger*
```

Now both `NoHandlerFoundException` and `swagger-ui` works fine.

Comment: This answer was very appreciated. Many other questions on this topic had suggesting using "static-locations" or enabling resource mapping entirely, but only "static-path-pattern" allowed Swagger to work without affecting exception handling.

Comment: This answer is really appreciated since I work with swagger and it enables us to customize and handle the no handler exception without affecting the swagger-ui.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because, using `@EnableWebMvc` disables MVC autoconfiguration and asks you to provide exactly what You want. Have a look at this [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-switch-off-default-mvc-configuration) 
You can either use other means to customize your configuration, such as a `@Configuration`
See Boot's ***WebMvcAutoConfiguration*** to find out what the defaults are, and copy over the pieces that you need.
This Link might help You as well -> [LINK](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-enablewebmvc-and-common-use-cases)

> What should you do when you want to customize your beans? As usual, extend WebMvcConfigurerAdapter (annotate the new class with @Component) and do your customizations.
>   So, bottom line of the particular problem: Don’t use @EnableWebMvc in
>   Spring Boot, just include spring-web as a maven/gradle dependency and
>   it will be autoconfigured.

This answer on stackoverflow shows how to do this .. check this [LINK3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661289/spring-boot-not-serving-static-content/25959419)

Comment: Is there an option for not using @EnableWebMvc?

Comment: Yes. Did You check the last link I added in the answer. That describes it.