# The Swagger UI doesn't work when "spring.resources.static-locations" is used

Tags: spring, swagger-ui

I would like to ask for your help regarding the following problem.

Unfortunately, the Swagger doesn't work, I get 404 page not found exception (http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html) when I use "spring.resources.static-locations" to specify the UI.

Does anybody face this problem? Could you help how I can manage this issue?

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are still dealing with this issue, I recommend [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55222174/8304083):

```
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/swagger*
```

I similarly had issues with using static-locations, but static-path-pattern allowed Swagger to work without disrupting my exception handling.