# Spring MVC: how to intercept 404 before returning error page/response?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

In my Spring Boot 2.2.x web application I need to intercept 404 errors so I can execute some custom logic before the error page is rendered or the json with error info is returned.

What's the correct way to achieve this?

At the moment I'm trying with a `@ControllerAdvice` class, but I don't know which exception to handle with the `@ExceptionHandler` method (if any is thrown)...

**NOTE**: I have already tried to intercept `NoHandlerFoundException`, but this doesn't seem to work... (the handler is not triggered).

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ErrorHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    public void handleException() {
        System.out.println("It's a 404!");
    }
}
```

I also enabled this in my `application.properties`:

```
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
```

Any other suggestion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handle error 404 with Spring controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356549/handle-error-404-with-spring-controller)

Comment: `NoHandlerFoundException` as mentioned by one of answer below is good choice.

Comment: @VishwaRatna I can't intercept this exception using ExceptionHandler. The handler is not triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution (or part of it) in this question: [Custom exception handler for NoHandlerFoundException is not working without @EnableWebMvc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49167033/1061499)

By default Spring doesn't throw an exception for 404 errors. You need to enable this property in `application.properties` (or yaml):

```
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
```

But you also need to set this property:

```
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern: /static
```

This restriction prevents Spring to search for static contents matching the missing path/handler.

Now you can intercept a `NoHandlerFoundException` as usual with `@ExceptionHandler`.

**NOTE** Before setting the `spring.mvc.static-path-pattern` property I tried to add `@EnableWebMvc` to a configuration class in my project: this way the `NoHandlerFoundException` was thrown but I obviously lost all the Spring Boot autoconfigurations.

Answer (score 1):

Use `NoHandlerFoundException`. This maps to 404 in spring boot.

Comment: I added the ErrorHandler code to my question. At the moment in my project I have just this class and the Application class to start the app.

Answer (score 0):

In the same class you use `@ControllerAdvice` implement `ErrorController`.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerAdvice implements ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public ResponseEntity<Map> handleError(HttpServletResponse response) {
        Map errorMapJson = new HashMap();

        if(response.getStatus() == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value()) {
            errorMapJson.put("type", "404 Error");
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<Map>(errorMapJson, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "/error";
    }
}
```