# Override the handleNoHandlerFoundException

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want override the Spring Boot default result when calling a not-existing route:

```json
{
    "timestamp": "2022-03-20T17:01:07.453+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "path": "/api/v1/not-found"
}
```

I have a `ControllerAdvisor`

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerAdvisor extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
  @Override
  protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleNoHandlerFoundException(NoHandlerFoundException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
      return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(new ErrorResponse("path not found"));
  }
}
```

that it works for others custom exception.

I have also added (or removed) this property on application.properties but nothing change:

`spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true`

Spring boot starter parent is v. 2.6.4

Comment: You can catch the exception throws by Spring when no handler is found for a request. Details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30329543/spring-boot-taking-control-of-404-not-found

Comment: Do you find a solution @sineverba

Answer (score 0):

Add following property in your application.properties:

```
spring.web.resources.add-mappings=false
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still looking an answer:

1. Define your custom ExceptionHandler that extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.
2. Override the methode handleNoHandlerFoundException and return a ResponseEntity with your custom Error object.
3. Add the following properties in your application.properties file:

   spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true

   spring.web.resources.add-mappings=false