# Return incorrect error response when handle exception

Tags: spring-boot

Spring Boot

```
@RestController
public class ProductsController {
  @PostMapping("/product")
    public ResponseEntity<Product> createProduct(@RequestBody String payload) {
        Product product = new Gson().fromJson(payload, Product.class);
        checkProduct(product);
        product.setCreated(new Date());
        if (product.getPrice() == null) {
            throw new InvalidParameterException("Invalid price");
        }
        logger.info("createProduct: product:\n" + product);
        return new ResponseEntity<Product>(product, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Here my custom handler of exception InvalidParameterException:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(InvalidParameterException.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleInvalidParameterException(InvalidParameterException ex,
                                                                     WebRequest request) {
        ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse(ex.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity(error, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
                                                                  HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status,
                                                                  WebRequest request) {
        List<String> details = new ArrayList<>();
        for(ObjectError error : ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors()) {
            details.add(error.getDefaultMessage());
        }
        ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse("Validation Failed", details);
        return new ResponseEntity(error, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

But when start request without price:

```
# Create  product without price
POST :BASE_URL:URL_SUFFIX/product
:HEADERS

{
  "name": "product name_1"
}
```

response is:

```
   {
      "timestamp": "2020-09-08T23:25:25.514+00:00",
      "status": 500,
      "error": "Internal Server Error",
      "message": "",
      "path": "/api/v1/product"
}
```

But result must be:

```
 {
          "timestamp": "2020-09-08T23:25:25.514+00:00",
          "status": 400,
          "error": "Bad request",
          "message": "Invalid price",
          "path": "/api/v1/product"
    }
```

Why not correct error response?

I got error:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter found for return value of type: class myproject.model.ErrorResponse
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:230) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:219) ~[spring-webmvc-
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24338734/responseentityexceptionhandler-is-not-getting-called-when-exception-occurs - maybe this helps.

Comment: @joy The problem was that one of the nested objects in ErrorResponse didn't have any getter/setter